# About insert shell commands into python

Tags: python, shell

I've inserted some shell commands into python script like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys,re
import gzip
import commands

path = "/home/x/nearline"

for file in os.listdir(path):
  if re.match('.*\.recal.fastq.gz', file):
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, file)
    result = commands.getoutput('zcat fullpath |wc -l')
    numseqs = int(result)/4.0
  print numseqs
```

`zcat fullpath |wc -l` is the shell command inserted.

Problem is, I define `fullpath` here for all `fastq` files, but after being put under `' '`, seems this `fullpath` doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to concatenate the string with the value of the variable:

```
result = commands.getoutput('zcat ' + fullpath + ' |wc -l')
```

Comment: Also, you're better off using `for aFile in glob.glob(path+'/*.recal.fastq.gz')` rather than bothering with `os.listdir()` and `os.path.join()`.

Comment: Even if there weren't the option of using `glob` here, the normal, simple spelling of `re.match('.*\.recal.fastq.gz', file)` is `file.endswith('.recal.fastq.gz')` (assuming you meant to escape the other dots in the regex too).

Answer (score 3):

`fullpath` is a variable, you need to concatenate it with the rest of command like this:

`result = commands.getoutput('zcat ' + fullpath + ' |wc -l')`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
commands.getoutput('zcat ' + fullpath + ' |wc -l')
```

since python variables aren't auto-expanded in strings.

Comment: This actually won't work...you omitted spaces around `fullpath`

Comment: True. Corrected, though I'd better delete this answer when there's 3 identical ones.